# Unlock partition on gParted

Tags: gparted, ntfs

Can anyone explain how I can make a partition to install Windows 10, with gParted? The main partitions are locked, as shown in the screenshot.

[image: gparted partition table]

I am a beginner and I am struggling with several issues, so I need Windows 10 along with Linux.

Comment: Be sure to boot Windows installer in UEFI boot mode. It also will want multiple partitions, but should find & use your existing ESP - efi system partition. If you install in BIOS/MBR boot mode, it will convert drive to MBR erasing system. See:https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/configure-uefigpt-based-hard-drive-partitions#RecommendedPartitionConfigurations

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu won't let you touch the partition while you are using it.

In order to shrink it, you just have to use the USB stick you used to install Ubuntu, or create a new one from Startup Disk Creator (*preinstalled*). You can download the Ubuntu image [here](https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop).

Once you got your stick, just boot a live version of Ubuntu and as you said you are struggling with Ubuntu, just install Gparted and shrink your main partition from there.

*Please note you **DON'T** have to create a new partition once you have shrinked it*.

When you finish, you will just have to install Windows on that partition giving it format from the Windows installer. If you create another partition, Windows won't be able to recognise it, as it's another file system.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have no installed pop os and thought it was the same as Ubuntu. So to have both linux and win10 i have to make a USB boot with win 10 and delete/format the hole HD (256gb) and then install win10 first and then the linux distro?

Comment: No, you have tu create a booteable Ubuntu USB, then plug it in and select "try Ubuntu". Then open Gparted and shrink your partition.

Comment: And right after doing that, plug in your Windows USB or insert your disc, and install it on the partition you have created on the step before.

Comment: I only have one option and that is try pop os. It is auto instaling after around 10 seconds.....So how do i run gparted from there...?

Comment: Thanks Santiago. I tried "Let me try" version run and then run Gparted. I was first wurried I installed a new  version. Worked well

Comment: That sounds really good, glad I could help.